# SQL statement to get values that have one property but not another property

Tags: sql

I need a SQL statement that will find all OrderIDs within a table that have an ActivityID = 1 but not an ActivityID = 2

So here's an example table:

OrderActivityTable:

```
OrderID  // ActivityID
1       // 1
1       // 2
2       // 1
3       // 1
```

So in this example, OrderID - 1 has activity of 1 AND 2, so that shouldn't return as a result. Orders 2 and 3 have an activity 1, but not 2... so they SHOULD return as a result.

The final result should be a table with an OrderID column with just 2 and 3 as the rows.

What I HAD tried before was:

```
select OrderID, ActivityID from OrderActivityTable where ActivityID = 1 AND NOT ActivityID = 2
```

That doesn't seem to get the result I want. I think the answer is a little more complicated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an outer self-join for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderActivityTable t1
LEFT JOIN OrderActivityTable t2
ON t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID AND t2.ActivityID = 2
WHERE t1.ActivityID = 1
AND t2.OrderID IS NULL
```

You can also use the `WHERE NOT IN` solution of Mike Christensen, or the correlated subquery solution of alfasin, but in my experience this method usually has the best performance (I use MySQL -- results may be different in other implementations). In an ideal world, the DBMS would recognize that these are all the same, and optimize them equivalently.

Comment: `+1` - Agree this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
SELECT OrderID, ActivityID FROM OrderActivityTable
WHERE ActivityID = 1
AND OrderID NOT IN (select distinct OrderID from OrderActivityTable where ActivityID = 2);
```

This will select everything in `OrderActivityTable` where `ActivityID` is 1, but filter out the list of `OrderID` rows that contain an `ActivityID` of 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
select OrderID, ActivityID from OrderActivityTable t
where 
ActivityID = 1 AND  
NOT not exists (select 1 from OrderActivityTable tt 
 where tt.OrderID = t.OrderID AND
 tt.ActivityID = 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this statement:

```
SELECT OrderID, ActivityID 
FROM OrderActivityTable 
WHERE ActivityID = 1 
AND ActivityID NOT IN (2)
```